# How do you access the cl namespace from NVIDIA header files?

Tags: opencl

I am sorry if this is a noob question but I am new to C++ and part of the reason I am messing with openCL is to learn more C++.

I installed the CUDA SDK and it put openCL header files here:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\CL
```

I added the the following two directories to additional include directories in Visual C++:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\CL
```

But when I try to reference anything in the cl namespace, [like they do in this tutorial](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/) it does not work because cl is undefined.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.
Do you have a `using namespace cl;` line ?

Comment: using namespace cl; gives error "name must be a namespace"

Comment: I think you've downloaded the C bindings, not the C++ ones. Where did you get those from? I've not got the CUDA SDK installed to check, but they might be installed elsewhere.

Comment: Aha, download this, put it in the same folder and `#include <cl.hpp>`: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/cl.hpp

Answer (score 1):

This problem has already been solved so I'm only writing here to add some information.

Instead of using the Nvidia CUDA SDK you can use the Intel or AMD SDK (I prefer Intel).  They both automatically include cl.hpp and support OpenCL 1.2 as well (Nvidia SDK only supports OpenCL 1.1).  You may need to add #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS to make sure your kernel works on Nvidia devices.

The SDK has nothing to do with the device driver which compiles and runs the kernel.  That is done by a vendor's video driver.  In fact you can install the Nvidia video drivers, the AMD Radeon drivers (even if you don't have a AMD video card), and the Intel OpenCL drivers.  Then you can compile your host code with e.g. the Intel OpenCL SDK and run your on kernel on Nvidia GPUs and Intel/AMD CPUs.

Comment: If cuda has gl_interop then you can use gl space then useing cl_gl interop can give a link between cuda and opencl maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that *nVidia*'s OpenCL framework (bundled with *CUDA*) doesn't come with the C++ wrapper library. But fortunately that one is a single header-only library using the existing OpenCL C API under the hood. So all you need to do is to download the [official `cl.hpp`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/cl.hpp) from *Khronos* and include it in your source file (after putting it into an accessible include directory, best together with *nVidia*'s own OpenCL headers). In fact you don't need to include any other header once you include and use `cl.hpp`.

But be aware that this C++ wrapper only works for OpenCL 1.1 (and is anything but the best C++ wrapper one can come up with either), but *nVidia* doesn't have OpenCL 1.2 support anyway.